# Python script in crontab not executing

Tags: python

I have a python script, for simplicity let's say all it does is this:

`print(os.listdir("/Users/me/folder"))`

The file is saved in `/Users/me/scripts/my-script.py`

From the terminal, I can run `cd /Users/me/scripts && /usr/bin/python my-script.py`. It successfully lists all the files and folders in /Users/me/folder.

I go to `crontab -e` and add
`* * * * * cd /Users/me/scripts && /usr/bin/python /Users/me/scripts/my-script.py`

I get stdrr message (after piping) of

```
  File "/Users/me/scripts/my-script.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(os.listdir("/Users/me/folder"))
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/me/folder'
```

I have followed a bunch of other answers on here, made sure it's not running as sudo in crontab -e, not cding to the script dir first, cding first and then putting relative path the script.

The script is executing no problem, it's just for whatever reason python is not running with permission to access the /Users/me folder - even though the cron was installed under the user me.

Comment: try with `sudo` in the start. The problem is the OS is not allowing python to access the folder

Comment: The paths suggest that you are on a Mac. I think this is related to specific OS-level security features for recent versions of macOS.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted

Comment: For the record, there is no reason to `cd` into the directory to run the script, just like you don't have to `cd /bin` to run `ls`

Comment: is your os macos?

Comment: @AKD In order for `sudo` to work you would have to grant passwordless privileges to run `python` as a privileged user, which seems like a bad idea. (And even then it probably won't fix this specific problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd /Users/me/scripts` is not needed because your python code is not writing anything there, as you are calling script by its absolute path

/usr/bin/python - also not needed because in the script you must have mentioned the shebang to tell system that it is Python script.

script should shave suitable permissions `chmod +x /path/to/your/file.py.`

Also note that corn isn't designed to output anything on terminal.

If the above doesn't work,then probably you are working with mac,and because of your os `access control mechanism`. cron jobs can no longer access certain directories because they hold sensitive data. **Grant Full Disk Access to cron** https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/

Comment: Thanks - the full disk permission to cron did the trick!